# How can i create a ListView of specific no. of columns in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding

[image: My Results]
[image: Results i want]

I want to create a ListView with 3 columns, i am creating a GridView inside ListView tag, but this is not providing me the same results i want.

Attached is the picture i want as result.

This is the piece of code i am using.

```
[![<ListView Name="List1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,70,0,0" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.33,-0.562" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource myHeaderStyle}">
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="200" Width="200" LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Label Content="{Binding username}" Width="100" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            <Image Source="{Binding imageSource}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="200" Width="200" LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Label Content="{Binding username}" Width="100" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            <Image Source="{Binding imageSource}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="200" Width="200" LastChildFill="False" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Label Content="{Binding username}" Width="100" Height="200" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                            <Image Source="{Binding imageSource}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>][1]][1]
```

Comment: I can see no picture attached to see the result you want...

Comment: @KFactory please check again.

Comment: ok thanks, and is your code compiling ? can we see what you get ?

Comment: Yes my code is compiling and i have attached another picture of my results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The better way to do this is by using a `UniformGrid` as the `ItemsPanel` of the `ListView`.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
           <UniformGrid Columns="3" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    ...
</ListView>
```

---

Here is an example of doing this with a `ListBox` instead of a `ListView`, as discussed in the comments.  This is the way I would recommend, unless you need some of the special features of the `ListView`, as it will be more performant.

This uses the [AgentOctal.WpfLib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AgentOctal.WpfLib) NuGet package (I am the author of this package) for the base `ViewModel` class to provide the property change notifications and Command support.  You should be able to substitute any working method that properly implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` though.

XAML:

```
<Window
    x:Class="ColumnsTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListViewColumns"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowVm />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox
            Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=People}">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="3" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Border
                            Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                            Margin="4"
                            BorderBrush="Black"
                            BorderThickness="1">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            Command="{Binding Path=AddPersonCommand}"
            Content="Add Person" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

View models:

```
namespace ColumnsTest
{
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using AgentOctal.WpfLib;
    using AgentOctal.WpfLib.Commands;

    class MainWindowVm : ViewModel
    {
        public MainWindowVm()
        {
            People = new ObservableCollection<PersonVm>();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<PersonVm> People { get; }

        private ICommand _addPersonCommand;
        public ICommand AddPersonCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _addPersonCommand ?? (_addPersonCommand = new SimpleCommand((obj) =>
                                        {
                                            People.Add(new PersonVm() { Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() });
                                        }));
            }
        }

    class PersonVm : ViewModel
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { SetValue(ref _name, value); }
        }

    }
}
```

It produces he following result:
[image]

Comment: That was an easy solution. I jumped straight to my wish :-)

I appreciate

Comment: As a note, you may then also use a ListBox, the base class of ListView.

Comment: The main benefit of using `ListView` over a `ListBox` is that the `ListView` allows you to have multiple views of the data.  If you don't need that functionality, stick with a `ListBox`, as @Clemens mentioned; it is a much lighter control, and more performant.

Comment: Sounds good.
I am using ListView for now and is solves my issue perfectly.

Comment: As a side-note, I absolutely *love* the fact that WPF's `ListBox` is smart enough to figure out the proper behavior of the Left, Right, Up, and Down keys automatically when doing this.